# Extraño proceso en debug de Android

Tags: java, android

Estoy desarrollando un servicio en background para android que lance notificaciones pero mientras veía el debug encontré este peculiar log.

> AudioPolicyManager: [getDeviceForStrategy]::STRATEGY_MEDIA::
>   ----------------------(^u^)/--

Esa carita se repite en varias lineas similares, es propio de Android?

Comment: que versión de Android?

Comment: es un sony con android 4.4.2

Answer (score 1):

Pregunto que versión de sistema operativo Android usas, ya que puedes ver directamente en el código para ver si en realidad es un mensaje del sistema operativo:

Revisa en el repositorio si el método `getDeviceForStrategy()` o la clase `AudioPolicyManager` imprimen ese mensaje:

```
uint32_t AudioPolicyManager::getDeviceForStrategy(routing_strategy strategy)
```

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/hardware/msm7k/+/eclair-sholes-release/libaudio/AudioPolicyManager.cpp

#### Actualización:

Revisando el código de las versiones OS 4.4.2 que comenta el usuario y que contienen la clase `AudioPolicyManager`:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/hardware/libhardware_legacy/+/android-4.2.2_r1.2

no se encuentra que se este imprimiendo los caracteres `(^u^)/-`.

Podría tratarse seguramente de un SO modificado o un **[ROM](https://theunlockr.com/roms/android-roms/)**

Comment: Revisando esa fuente no veo ese tipo de comentario. Talvez el android editado por sony sobrecargo alguno de esos metodos?

Comment: Hola red2005, el código es del sistema operativo Eclair (android 2.0), entonces tal vez en el que comenta el usuario se encuentra 4.4.2

Comment: No, debe ser un OS modificado o un ROM.